# Adding custom google map marker / pin (color)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've done pretty decent getting some google map customizations; but I'm wondering where / or what I can add below to simply change the map marker / pin / or icon. I am really seeking to just change the color; but will create an image and do it that way if I must.

Below is what I am working with; cheers/

```
window.onload = function() {  

function initialize() {
    var stylez = [
      {
        featureType: "all",
        stylers: [
          { hue: "#c3c367" },
          { saturation: -75 }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "label",
        stylers: [
          { visibility: "off" }
        ]
      }
    ];

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.101958, -118.327925), // toggle per data

        mapOptions = {
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, "Edited"] 
            },
            zoom: 14,
            center: latlng
        },

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions),

        styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(stylez, {name: "Edited"}),

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng, 
            map: map, 
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title:"Hello World!"
        }),

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<div><img width='50' height='50' src='assets/icos/homico.png'</div>"
        });

        map.mapTypes.set("Edited", styledMapType);
        map.setMapTypeId('Edited');

    function toggleBounce () {
        if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
    }

    // Add click listener to toggle bounce
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        toggleBounce();
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        setTimeout(toggleBounce, 1500);
    });
}

// Call initialize -- in prod, add this to window.onload or some other DOM ready alternative
initialize();

};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to add

```
"icon": "url"
```

to your marker declaration. So This:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng, 
        map: map, 
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title:"Hello World!"
    })
```

Becomes:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng, 
        map: map,
        icon: yourIconUrl,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title:"Hello World!"
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

I already answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267428/google-map-api-marker-with-letter-on-map/20267508#20267508), does it solve your problem ?

You can customize your own marker using this URL :

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=D|00FF00|000000
```

`chld` parameter is the letter you want to appear in your marker.
After the pipe, the first RGB code if the color of the marker, the second is the background color of the marker. The last one is optional.

So you can create your marker like this :

```
var myPin= new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=D|00FF00|000000");
```

and use it like you want !

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a MarkerImage:

```js
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(img_path+'marker.png',
    // This marker is 48 pixels wide by 48 pixels tall.
    new google.maps.Size(24, 24),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 12,24.
    new google.maps.Point(12, 24)
);
```

The dimensions of the image and the anchor point will put your custom icon on the correct place

And specify the icon when you create the marker:

```js
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      //(...)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In [react-native-map](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md) there is a [pinColor](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/887) attribute that controls what color the pin is.

```
<Marker
  pinColor={isActive ? 'yellow' : 'red'}
  key={`${markerId}-${isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive'}`}
  // ... other props ...
/>
```