# Google Maps : Change markers color only if they are in same location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there an easy way to change the google map marker icon but only if they are exactly on same location ? For example, all my markers are blue, but at the coord 48.2, 67.5 are placed 2 markers, so I want them red.

ps : I use Overlapping Marker Spiderfier if it can help.

Comment: What does your code look like?  You need to process through all the markers looking for duplicates and changing the icon to red for the duplicates.  That would be simpler to do when the markers are added to the map (how do you do that?) or in the original data.

Comment: I'm doing your algorithm, but I just request if there is an easy way to do it. My code doesn't matter.

Comment: There's no simple way, the only complexity effect will be where in the execution you check. As @geocodezip said it would be simplest when adding the markers, or to modify the original data set to indicate duplicates (if you're using a web service or database).

Comment: [Similar question (but about combining content of the infowindow)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708252/google-maps-multiple-markers-with-the-exact-same-location-not-working/17710624#17710624)

Comment: Your code does matter.  Unless you are looking for us to work for you for free.  Knowing what you are doing would have saved me wasting the time adding the comment above.  Making your code more efficient is not possible without knowing what your are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Overlapping Marker Spiderfier then you must be keeping an array of markers correct?

The simplest way would be to loop through the array each time you create a new marker and check the coordinates. If they match then swap the icon of both to the new colour.

Information on changing the icon itself can be found at: [Adding custom google map marker / pin (color)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659565/adding-custom-google-map-marker-pin-color/20659820#20659820), there's a few options there.