# Unable to add text on google maps marker using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using C# visual studio 2010 for locating area on google maps. Here is my code to do so:-

```
public partial class frmMap : Form
    {
        public frmMap(string lat, string lon)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (lat == string.Empty || lon == string.Empty)
            {
                this.Dispose();
            }

            try
            {
                StringBuilder queryAddress = new StringBuilder();
                queryAddress.Append("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=");

                if (lat != string.Empty)
                {
                    queryAddress.Append(lat + "%2C");
                }

                if (lon != string.Empty)
                {
                    queryAddress.Append(lon);
                }

                webBrowser1.Navigate(queryAddress.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

which is working fine, Now I need to add some text on marker of google maps. for this I search every where on google, but unable to find a way to add text on google maps marker. So, is there any way to edit marker text on google maps using C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google map API marker with letter on map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267428/google-map-api-marker-with-letter-on-map)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1771915/4972575
(you probably need an google API key to add custom marker.)

You can make a custom marker with chart.apis.google.com:
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=2|45|FFFFFF|14|_|your|text