# Google maps API v3 - label and color for marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I had a problem of defining my own marker label and a marker color, so I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267428/google-map-api-marker-with-letter-on-map/20267508#20267508).
According to it I can define my marker object as follows with the help of google chart API:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
  position:latlng,
  map:map,
  icon:'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|00FF00|000000'
});
```

But in a [recent post of "Geo Developers Blog"](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/08/labels-meets-markers-with-google-maps.html), I found out that they have introduced a new label property for the marker. Now I can easily define a label for the marker as follows:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
  position:latlng,
  map:map,
  label: 'A'
});
```

I need to know whether I can define a marker color (not the text color of the label) the same way so that my marker object would look something like:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
  position:latlng,
  map:map,
  label: 'A', //my label
  color: 00FF00 //my marker color 
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option would be to use [SVG Symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    label: "0",
    icon: pinSymbol('red')
});
function pinSymbol(color) {
    return {
        path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 1,
        scale: 1,
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(0,-29)
    };
}
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.605, -122.333);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    label: "0",
    icon: pinSymbol('red')
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.5, -122.0),
    label: "A",
    icon: pinSymbol('#00FF00')
  });
  bounds.extend(marker1.getPosition());
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6, -122.2),
    label: "B",
    icon: pinSymbol('orange')
  });
  bounds.extend(marker2.getPosition());
  var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.7, -122.1),
    label: "C",
    icon: pinSymbol('yellow')
  });
  bounds.extend(marker3.getPosition());
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function pinSymbol(color) {
  return {
    path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
    fillColor: color,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    scale: 1,
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```